# Is $\bigl(X(X-a)(X-b)\bigr)^{2^n} +1$ an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, with $a\neq b$ and $ab\neq 0$, and $n$ a positive integer.

> Is the polynomial $\bigl(X(X-a)(X-b)\bigr)^{2^n} +1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

I know that $\bigl(X(X-a)\bigr)^{2^n} +1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, but I have a hard time generalizing my proof with three factors.

PS: This is not homework (and may even be open).

Comment: Why is this tagged "cyclotomic polynomial"?

Comment: @Zev, because the proof I have for 2 factors uses cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: Cool question, got me thinking.  Would you mind explaining how you know that ${(X(X - a))}^{2^n} + 1$ is irreducible over Q?

Comment: Robert, not sure I can detail enough in the comment box, but if $a=0$ it's trivial (cyclotomic), suppose $a\neq 0$, let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ a root, and $\mathbb{Q}[z]$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}[z(z-a)]$. Looking at the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ we show that $\mathbb{Q}[z(z-a)] \neq \mathbb{Q}[z]$ and we conclude with the fact that $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}[z(z-a)]=2^n$.

Comment: @user84673:  can you do anything with the case $b = 0$, i.e. with ${{(X^2(X - a))}^{2^n}} + 1$?

Comment: @user84673: Could you explain why $z \not\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, or, what is the same, why $x^2-ax-\zeta$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, where $\zeta= e^{2\pi i/2^n}$?

Comment: This is far from an open question since it is a special case of an old conjecture of Schur proved long time ago by Seres. If I understand well you want to use [Capelli's Lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132853/capelli-lemma-for-polynomials) in order to prove the irreducibility. You said (but didn't show us!) that you were succesful for the product of two distinct polynomials $X$ and $X-a$. I'm eager to see a proof on this line at least for some particular cases like these. (I don't know a proof of Schur conjecture using Capelli's Lemma, if there is one.)

Comment: Schur's conjecture was the following: if $f(X)=X^{2^n}+1$, $n\ge 1$, and $g(X)=(X-a_1)\cdots(X-a_m)$ with $a_i\in\mathbb Z$ distinct, then $f(g(X))$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks YACP for the positive answer and reference. I started the the outline of the proof for the case $X(X-a)$, 3rd comment from the top. Here is the end of the outline. Let $P$ be the minimal polynomial mentioned, and suppose that the field extension is trivial. Denote $b=(a/2)^{2^{n-1}}$ and $c=b^2+1$, with some calculation involving $P(X)P(a-X)$ you get $b^4=(c-1)(c+1)$, and show that it is a contradiction.

Answer (score -2):

Call $f$ your polynomial. Then $f$ is not irreducible if and only if there exists a root $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ of $f$. If a such root exists then, for $n\geq 1$ we have  $$0\leq(x(x-a)(x-b))^{2^n}=-1.$$

I leave the case $n=0$ to you.

Comment: $(X^2+1)^2$ has no rational roots. (-1)